# Cache and Spring

Tags: java, spring, caching

I want to know about some cache libraries to be used with spring. I want the cache to be centralised distributed as I have multiple servers.This also rules out guava(in-memory cache). Redis/Jedis and Couchbase are two options but with lacking support for java. They need all java objects/beans to be serializable. Guava supports java but is in-process. Redisson seems good but I read that it lacks support and maintenance compared to Jedis.

I want to prevent code changes to a great extent, and thus don't want my beans to implement Serializabe, neither do I want to convert my objects to Json or Strings.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching-gemfire/

Comment: jedis cluster is still under development

Comment: Requests for software recommendations are off-topic folks ...

Comment: @Mr Spoon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279117/can-jedis-get-set-an-java-pojo

Comment: Selection libraries  depends on the using.

Comment: @StephenC I haven't asked something like please tell me a good download manager, its a cache lib to be used with spring that suits my reqs.

Comment: @GrzegorzBylica I am shifting from single server to multiple servers, hence in-memory cache needs to be upgraded to centralized or distributed cache. Famous centralized/distributed solutions like couchbase and redis aren't specifically designed for cache storage although they provide these facilities, hence the lacking support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me your requirements are contrary to each other.
You need to choose one of

1. **No serialization** of any kind. But that works only for cache in **single JVM**.
2. **Distributed cache**. Data stored outside of application JVM. Possible to many nodes. But that requires **serialization** of some kind. Be it java serialization, JSON, Arvo, Kryo, Parquet, protocollBuffers.. Data be transfered over the network in serialized form.

No matter what you choose, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html will help you. It has support for

- JDK ConcurrentMap-based Cache
- Ehcache-based Cache
- Caffeine Cache
- Guava Cache
- GemFire-based Cache
- JSR-107 Cache

Why you believe that `Redis/Jedis and Couchbase are lacking support for java`?
They have very good support, but your objects must be serialized.

For Redis, it is supported as cache abstraction by http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.7.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction

Similar project exist for Couchbase  https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-spring-cache

Comment: Yes, I missed that. Something which needs to be sent over the network needs to be serialized.