# Can DataSource object be cached in Redis

Tags: redis

Does Redis allow caching of the javax.sql.DataSource object? I read Redis does not allow all types of objects to be cached.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? what is DataSource?

Comment: @GuyKorland , javax.sql.DataSource.

Comment: Can you check if [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584504/how-to-use-java-object-as-a-value-in-redis) you out? It would seem that, depending on the client you plan to use you might get that out of the box. Failing that, you should able to store any kind of object if you can serialize/deserialize them.